# C#, socket communication (external connection)

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a question about C# communication.

Currently using .Net and studying Socket. You can create a socket server using the internal IP and connect as an internal client. Is it possible to open a server in another network like a chat program and connect to Socket Ip:Port from another network?

```
Socket sListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.20"), 8000);
    
sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
sListener.Listen(20);
Socket sClient = sListener.Accept();
```

Is there anything I need to configure to open the server using the above IP and port number and connect to the server from another network (Client)?

Thank you :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. I draw a little image for a normal connection over the internet.

[image: Normal connection over internet]

### What you have to do?

1. Open a port in your router (aka enable port-forward) and forward `60800` to `192.168.0.20:8000`.
2. Determine your external ip. Google for "what is my ip" or go to my [site](https://ip.akop.online/).
3. Connect the via `your-external-ip:60800`.

Hint: `60800` can be any other random port-value. I suggest high random numbers, so that hacker/scanner can't discover your service so fast.

That is very basic. I recommend, that you start learn how the ip-communication is working.

Comment: thank you !!
When you open the server by specifying a random port as 192.168.0.20:60800 and connect with an external IP, you can get the IP address and allow the IP and port!?

Comment: I don't got the question. You don't have to change the server code (it's still running on port `8000`). Your router allows all connections to the random port.